# How to Join multple table in R2DBC and Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

//1. Person Entity

```
class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    Private Address addId;
}
```

//2. Address Entity

```
class Address {
    private Integer addId;
    private String city;
    Private String state;
    Private String country;
    Private Integer zip;  
}
```

3. How to Join multple table in R2DBC and Spring WebFlux?

Answer (score 0):

Currently R2DBC doesnt support annotation such as @OneToMany. So in Address you shuld have a property called userId of type Integer and pertsist Person and then persist Address. And to get them you should first get the Person and find the Address by the userId